# My android studio application unfortunately stopped in my device Redmi 2 Prime, but it's working in Nexus emulator

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agte.agtevivo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity android:name=".Register"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also I have 2 activities: Login and Register, but not connected with database. It's just a link. I have started with android Marshmallow but that changed to Kitkat in configuration. What can I do?

Updated error about resource

```
  C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\AgteVivo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\flavor\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml

  Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processFlavorDebugResources'.
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command    'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My build gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.agte.agtevivo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavor {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you be more Specific?

Comment: hi ,Am beginner in android studio i already create 3 activity one login and then register.In main activity i designed the screen i want to get after login.

Comment: Ok.. Now whats the issue?

Comment: Can you post your log error first?

Comment: But am running its create nexus 5 device as emulator it will shows my app but too slow os that i given on that is marshmallow.when am debugging or export that in to apk and use in my mobile(redmi 2 prime kitkat) its shows unfortunatly stop.also am try to create emulator with same spec but same problem founded please help

Comment: Ok Post your log error..

Comment: where did i got my log file.?

Comment: Run the App.. And when error occurs.. Find it in the logCat/Console.. if you are using Android Studio

Comment: 18:20:19 Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
18:20:20 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
         java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)

Comment: at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:573)
         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:545)
         at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMoni... (show balloon)

Comment: these are shown in event log

Comment: but in my gradle console shows build successfully

Comment: No what I meant is.. When crash has occurred the console will print out error in Red color.. Post that error log..

Comment: Also try to put the error log in question itself.. Not in comment.. It will be easier for to understand what went wrong

Comment: And its not the Gradle build Console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472521/android-studio-shows-error-when-running-my-app-with-emulator-redmi-2-prime-kitkat  new questin added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472521/android-studio-shows-error-when-running-my-app-with-emulator-redmi-2-prime-kitkat please help

Comment: Ok i have found the problem..

Comment: Are you using any bitmap code in you Activity?

Comment: yes,is there bitmap code means image or other.? ya am added image as background  and one image button in main activity

Comment: OK.. I will post this as an answer.. Accept if found useful

Comment: sir another problem i found that now my gradle finish with 103 errors thats about some Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.same no resource that found

Comment: if you can please help me

Comment: for the resource not found error.,. Updating the support library will fix the error.. :) :)

Comment: if still error occurs.. change the compile sdk version to 23 or higher

Comment: Are you using Android studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: am using android studio